# Ошибка в книге Страуструпа( C++ 98)

Tags: c++

Привожу цитату из книги Страуструпа:
"... эта техника использует тот факт, что статически размещаемые обьекты без конструкторов инициализируются нулем."...
Речь идет о примере с классом со статическим bool, но я как не пробовал, это не так

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

class Row {
    static bool b;
    int i;
    //...
public:
    Row(int row) : i(row) {}
    bool isRed() { b = i % 2 ? true : false; return b; }
    void chow_color()
    {
        std::string s;
        s = isRed() ? "red" : "black";
        std::cout << s;
    }
    //...
};
//bool Row::b = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication qca(argc, argv);
    Row n(5);
    n.chow_color();
    return qca.exec();
    // как только я убираю инициализацию static b компилятор выдает ошибку
    // error: undefined reference to `Row::b'
}
```

В чем ошибка - в книге или в моем компиляторе?...

Comment: Причем здесь undefined reference и инициализация? Вы можете убрать инициализатор в своем примере `bool Row::b;` и b будет инициализирован нулем и так.

Comment: да , но в его примере   и  такого определения нет

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Инициализацией в С++ называется процесс назначения начального значения объекту. В вашем случае в

```
bool Row::b = 0;
```

к явной инициализации относится только `= 0` часть. Ее можно убрать и ничего не изменится, как правильно и говорится в книге Страуструпа.

Само же

```
bool Row::b;
```

убирать ни в коем случае нельзя. Это *определение* статического члена класса и для *неконстантного* статического члена оно должно присутствовать обязательно. (Более того, в педантичной трактовке классического С++98, оно требуется даже для *константных* статических членов целочисленных типов, хотя не все компиляторы С++98 будут настаивать на этом.)

В современном С++ (С++17) вы вместо этого можете сделать

```
class Row {
  static inline bool b; // `= 0;`, если предпочитаете
  ...
};
```

и дополнительное определение уже не понадобится.

---

Книга Страуструпа существенно меньше по объему, чем стандарт языка, даже если сравнивать части, ответственные только за описание core language, без стандартной библиотеки. Поэтому там ожидаемо будет содержатся большое количество упрощений и намеренных "ошибок", призванных избавить изложение от [пока] ненужных деталей и облегчить понимание языка начинающими. Например (известная ошибка), вы можете там прочитать, что у всех типов есть конструкторы. Это формально является ошибочным утверждением, ибо конструкторы в С++ бывают только у классов.

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, в вашем понимании проблемы...

[Вот](https://ideone.com/RbN2Dz), все варианты работают:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Row {
public:
    static bool b;
};
bool Row::b;

bool v;

bool get()
{
    static bool z;
    return z;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << Row::b << endl;
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << get() << endl;
}
```

Вы обратили внимание, о **какой** ошибке сообщает компилятор?

Comment: Harry, да, я мог и неинициализировать, но в книге пример без такого определения, поэтому я запутался. В любом случаи + за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что запись `//bool Row::b = 0;` которую вы убираете одновременно является определением и явной инициализацией. Ошибка при сборке появляется из-за отсутствия определения. Но инициализацию действительно можно опустить и `b` все равно будет инициализировано 0.

```
bool Row::b;
```

Это поведение отличается от поведения при создании локальных переменных:

```
int main()
{
    bool c; // остается неинициализирована
}
```

Кроме того, в книге есть неточность: нулем инициализируются вообще все статически размещенные объекты. Если у них еще есть конструктор он будет вызван после инициализации нулями во время фаза динамической инициализации.